# Trying to convert WIF 4.0 custom STS (from project template) to use .NET 4.5

Tags: wif, .net-4.5

I have successfully created a working custom STS using the project templates for the passive and active cases that came with the most recent WIF SDK (for .NET 4.0). Everything works as desired.

I am now trying to upgrade my web applications and services to .NET 4.5, including my custom STS. I have been able to map all of the namespaces/classes from Microsoft.IdentityModel.xxx to the new namespaces/classes built into the framework with 1 exception - WSTrustServiceHostFactory.

That class no longer seems to exist, and I cannot figure out how to replace the functionality it provided. Namely, from this link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.protocols.wstrust.wstrustservicehostfactory

```
<%@ServiceHostLanguage="C#"Debug="true"Service="XXX.XXX.MyActiveSTSConfiguration"Factory="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustServiceHostFactory"%>
```

My passive STS is currently working after upgrading to 4.5. I need to find an appropriate/recommended method of instantiating an active SecurityTokenService using the 4.5 framework (ideally, using web.config for most configuration as in the SDK project templates). Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This turned out to be pretty simple once I figured a few things out.

Service host markup:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="XXX.XXX.MyActiveSTSConfiguration" Factory="XXX.XXX.CustomWSTrustServiceHostFactory" %>
```

Here's my custom factory class implementation. The key is that since you can no longer use WSTrustServiceFactory to create a WSTrustServiceHost for you, you have to explicitly create one yourself in the CreateServiceHost method overrides.

```
public class CustomWSTrustServiceHostFactory 
    : ServiceHostFactory {

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="CustomWSTrustServiceHostFactory"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public CustomWSTrustServiceHostFactory() 
        : base() { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates and configures a <see cref="WSTrustServiceHost"/> with a specific base address.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="serviceType">Specifies the type of service to host (ignored).</param>
    /// <param name="baseAddresses">The <see cref="T:Uri"/> array that contains the base addresses for the service.</param>
    /// <returns>A <see cref="WSTrustServiceHost"/> with a specific base address.</returns>
    protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses) {
        var config = new PortalActiveSTSConfiguration();
        var host = new WSTrustServiceHost(config, baseAddresses);
        //var host = base.CreateServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses);
        var serviceBehavior = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceBehaviorAttribute>();
        serviceBehavior.AddressFilterMode = AddressFilterMode.Any;
        return host;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates and configures a <see cref="WSTrustServiceHost"/> with a specific base address.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="constructorString">The constructor string (ignored).</param>
    /// <param name="baseAddresses">The <see cref="T:Uri"/> array that contains the base addresses for the service.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public override ServiceHostBase CreateServiceHost(string constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses) {
        var config = new PortalActiveSTSConfiguration();
        var host = new WSTrustServiceHost(config, baseAddresses);
        //var host = base.CreateServiceHost(constructorString, baseAddresses);
        var serviceBehavior = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceBehaviorAttribute>();
        serviceBehavior.AddressFilterMode = AddressFilterMode.Any;
        return host;
    }

}
```

Custom service configuration class implementation (basically what came with the WIF 4.0 STS template):

```
public class MyActiveSTSConfiguration 
    : SecurityTokenServiceConfiguration {

    public MyActiveSTSConfiguration()
        : base(
            WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings[ISSUER_NAME],
                new X509SigningCredentials(
                    CertificateUtil.GetCertificate(
                        StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
                        WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings[SIGNING_CERTIFICATE_THUMBPRINT], 
                        true)
                )
        ) {
        this.SecurityTokenService = typeof(MyActiveSTS);
    }

}
```